# Example for using JQuery DirtyForms plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-dirtyforms

I am using the jQuery DirtyForms plugin to prevent users from inadvertently leaving a page without saving.  I'm running into some trouble with the dialog box.  I have two buttons: Cancel and Don't Save.

The Cancel action is working correctly: the dialog closes and the new page is not loaded.  However, the Don't Save action is not working.  The new page should be loaded, but it's not happening.

I must be missing something obvious.  Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('form').dirtyForms();
    });

    $('a').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

            if($.DirtyForms.isDirty()){
                    $("#dialog-savechanges").dialog({
                            height: 250,
                            width: 500,
                            modal: true,
                            buttons: {
                                    Cancel: function() {
                                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                            $.DirtyForms.choiceContinue = false;
                                            $.DirtyForms.choiceCommit(event);
                                    },
                                    "Don't Save": function() {
                                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                            $.DirtyForms.choiceContinue = true;
                                            $.DirtyForms.choiceCommit(event);
                                    }
                            }
                    });
            }
    });

</script>

<div id="dialog-savechanges" title="Save Changes?">
    <p>You've made changes to this page. Do you want to leave this page without saving?</p>
</div>
```

Thank you!

-Steve

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508000/stop-page-from-unloading-within-the-beforeunload-event-handler#35536912) for the correct way to implement a save changes button.

Answer (score 7):

OK, I knew it was something obvious… hopefully this will help someone else.

The problem is the preventDefault function:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

After removing this, the dialog behaves as expected.