# Window.beforeunload display a custom popup instead of alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to alert users about unsaved changes before they leave a page.But i dont want to use the default alert box for that . Suppose consider calling popup Function displays the my designed alert box . How to replace it with the default alert box . Thanks you

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
  $('#myModalWarningBeforeLeaving').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop page from unloading within the beforeunload event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508000/stop-page-from-unloading-within-the-beforeunload-event-handler)